# What's the easist way to get BigQuery size at project level using command line tool?

Tags: google-bigquery

Wanted to find out BigQuery storage size for our entire project, I have script to loop through all tables and sum up their size, works but slow, is there a bq command I can do it easily?

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 7):

There are metatable called `__TABLES__` and `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`

You can run a query like:

```
SELECT sum(size_bytes) FROM <dataset>.__TABLES__
```

The `__TABLES__` portion of that query may look unfamiliar. `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is a meta-table containing information about tables in a dataset. You can use this meta-table yourself. For example, the query `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` will return metadata about the tables in the `publicdata:samples` dataset. You can also do `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES__`

**Available Fields:**

The fields of the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` meta-table (that are all available in the `TABLE_QUERY` query) include:

- `table_id`: name of the table.
- `creation_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was created. This is the same as the `creation_time` field on the table.
- `type`: whether it is a view (2) or regular table (1).

The following fields are *not* available in `TABLE_QUERY()` since they are members of `__TABLES__` but not `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`. They're kept here for historical interest and to partially document the `__TABLES__` metatable:

- `last_modified_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was updated (either metadata or table contents). Note that if you use the `tabledata.insertAll()` to stream records to your table, this might be a few minutes out of date.
- `row_count`: number of rows in the table.
- `size_bytes`: total size in bytes of the table.

Comment: I have used this to create this gist to compute the size of the entire project. You can find it here in case it's helpful: https://gist.github.com/orcaman/f5a230bbaa73aceb91a0bf96838b24eb